# Not able to install xdebug on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: xdebug, php-5.4

I am not able to install xdebug on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

The instruction I received from [xdebug wizard](http://xdebug.org/wizard.php) are as follows:-

1. Download `xdebug-2.4.0beta1.tgz`
2. Unpack the downloaded file with `tar -xvzf xdebug-2.4.0beta1.tgz`
3. Run: `cd xdebug-2.4.0beta1`
4. Run: `./configure`
5. Run: `make`
6. Run: `cp modules/xdebug.so /usr/lib/php5/20100525`
7. Update /`etc/php5/cli/php.ini` and change the line
   `zend_extension = /usr/lib/php5/20100525/xdebug.so`

On executing `.configure` I am getting the below error:-

```
checking Check for supported PHP versions... configure: error: not supported. Need a PHP version >= 5.4.0 (found 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.21)
```

But `php -v` is giving the below output:-

```
PHP 5.4.45-2+deb.sury.org~precise+2 (cli) (built: Oct  4 2015 16:12:54) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans
```

But `php-config --version` is reporting as follows (which is causing the problem):- 
`5.3.10-1ubuntu3.21`

I have upgraded Php to 5.4 as mentioned in this [link](http://www.pixelite.co.nz/article/upgrading-php-54-ubuntu-1204-lts-support-drupal-8/) under the section *"Add a PPA and install newer a newer version of PHP"*

Can someone let me know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing the upgrade as mentioned in this [link](http://www.pixelite.co.nz/article/upgrading-php-54-ubuntu-1204-lts-support-drupal-8/) `sudo apt-get upgrade` was used which held some of the packages from upgrading. Doing `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to upgrade all packages. The Simpler way is, to install latest php-config .

In case of different version of php-config --version and php --version.

To update php-config you have to install the latest php-dev .

if 
`php --version`
PHP 5.6.30-7+deb.sury.org~precise+1 (cli)

eg.

`sudo apt-get install php5.6-dev`

In above case it will be:
`sudo apt-get install php5.4-dev`